# Socket programming in Java. Accepting a device's connection requests

Tags: java, sockets

I have a device that tries to connect to a server periodically on a specific port (2001).
How do I establish a server in java that "waits" for this device to connect?

Comment: [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) is the first thing that comes up when you google socket programming java

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good intro to TCP socket programming in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479514/good-intro-to-tcp-socket-programming-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be simple, standard use of Java sockets.  Open a `ServerSocket` on 2001, and call it's `.accept()` method.  It will wait until it receives a connection, then return a connected `Socket` that can be read from / written to.